# DataGrid ColumnWidth Property ignored in DataTemplate for row details

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, column-width

This is the UserControl that displays the details from my application and as you can see the `ColumnWidth` Property is explicit set to `*`. I also tried to set the `Width` property from the `DataGridTextColumn`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfUserInterface.MyDetailsView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="185" d:DesignWidth="480">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" Margin="10">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column3"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the main window that only contains the DataGrid.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfUserInterface.Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window" Height="306" Width="453">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParentColumn1"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParentColumn2"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParentColumn3"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MyDetailsView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is what shows up on the screen when you run the application and select a row in the parent DataGrid.

[image: DataGrid]

When I set the width of the DataGrid in the `MyDetailsView` to a specified value like 400 the columns are sized perfect but this is not an option. Is there any way to solve this problem? A workaround?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. No matter I give ColumnWidth as * or value from any binding, it is simply ignored. However, giving an absolute value in xaml works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked about a year ago, but I've been facing the same problem and I've found out this solution:

```
 this.dgrData.Columns[0].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
 this.dgrData.Columns[1].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
 ...
```

Hope it may be of any help to someone.