# DataGridColumn - How to Bind the Visibility to DataGrid Width

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, converters

i try to show the user some not so important columns of my datagrid, only when enough space(width of the whole program) available is. so i wanna bind the visibility of the column to the actual with of the datagrid with a converter.
all of my converters, who i wrote works well, BUT in this case happens nothing, means there is no call of the converter. i checked that out by my debug log.

```
<mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="Kilometer" 
                        MinWidth="20" 
                        Width="SizeToCells"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=Kilometer, TargetNullValue='-', FallbackValue='-'}"  
                        Visibility="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, TargetNullValue=Collapsed, FallbackValue=Collapsed, Converter={StaticResource IntAsLimit2VisibilityCollapsed}, ConverterParameter=1300}"
                        />
```

made i something wrong? is it maybe in this combination not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073740/binding-visibility-for-datagridcolumn-in-wpf), DataGrid columns don't lie in Visual tree of DataGrid, and we can't get to outer `DataContext` using `RelativeSource`.
We can only use x:Reference to an external FrameworkElement.

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871551/binding-the-width-property-of-a-datagridcolumn-to-the-actualwidth-of-the-parent) is a similar question with a possible solution (you don't need to set a width and will probably avoid a circular reference).

Comment: thx a lot i did not found these links. :/ but know i remember: this proxy story, but one thing IS interesting, because that works:   <mui:DataGridTextColumn Header="ActualWidth" Binding="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid} }, TargetNullValue='-', FallbackValue='-'}" MinWidth="20" Width="SizeToCells" />